# How to write a file directly to Django FileField?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way in Python / DJango to write directly to a model's file field?

Suppose I have this model

```
# models.py
class Registry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    form = models.FileField(
        upload_to='registryform',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=500)
```

A normal workflow for generating a file and writing into it is:

```
with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('random text')
```

How can I write and save this file to the file field?

```
with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    # Write to registry.form using f.write
```

Comment: A filefield does *not* store the *content* of the file. It is basically a `CharField` that stores the location (like a path for example) of the file somewhere. Storing large binary data objects in a database is not efficient in disk space, but also in performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ContentFile` to directly store in your models, but first you need to read the file data.

```py
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

registry_instance = # some Registry object

with open('readme.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    content_file = ContentFile(data)
    registry_instance.form.save("filename.extension", content_file, save=False)
    registry_instance.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`BinaryField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) to store file contents:

```py
from django.db import models
 
class ModelWithBinaryField(models.Model):
    binary_field = models.BinaryField()

with open('readme.txt', 'rb') as f:
  obj = ModelWithBinaryField.objects.create(binary_field = f.read())
  obj.save()
```

[Additional example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binaryfield-django-models/)

Answer (score 0):

```py
class BinaryField(serializers.Field):
        
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.hex()
        
    def to_internal_value(self, value):
         return value

class WriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    form = BinaryField()
    class Meta:
        model =...
        fields = '__all__'

def post(self, request: Request):
    file = request.data['file']
    data = {"name": request.user.pk, 
            "form": file.read(),}
    serializer = WriteSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        doc = serializer.save()
        return Response({"id": doc.id})
    else:
        return Response({"id": None}, status=403)
```